# Php CRUD: show data from 2 related tables in a single while loop

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have made a CRUD application for gathering information about patients.

There are 2 tables in the data base: *users* and *medical_records*. The "users" table contains the *medical personal* that ads medical records, in other words, data to the *medical_records* table.

The user id (`uid`) is a foreign key in the medical records table. I want to display the full name of the medic in the *medical_records* table.

[image]

For this purpose, I have written this query, first of all:

```
$sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`" . $row['uid'] . "`";
```

and the result is the desired one:

```
SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`4;`
```

But echoing the full name like so `echo $row['first_name'] . $row['last_name'];` results in an error: `Undefined index: first_name in path\to\medical_records_all_table.php`.

The entire context where I am trying to extract data from two tables inside a single while loop is:

```
<table id="medical_records" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nume complet</th>
      <th>Judet</th>
      <th>Data internarii</th>
      <th>Ora internarii</th>
      <th>Data operatiei</th>
      <th>Ora operatiei</th>
      <th>Fisa adaugata de</th>
      <th>Actiuni</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT `mid`, `uid`, `nume_complet`, `judet`, `data_internarii_mamei`, `ora_internarii_mamei`, `data_operatiei`, `ora_operatiei` FROM medical_records";

      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $mid = $row['mid'];
          ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $mid; ?>">
      <td>
        <a href="view_record.php?mid=<?php echo $mid; ?>">
        <?php echo ucwords($row['nume_complet']); ?>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row['judet']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['data_internarii_mamei']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ora_internarii_mamei']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['data_operatiei']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ora_operatiei']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php
          echo $sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`" . $row['uid'] . ";`";
          echo $row['first_name'] . $row['last_name'];
        ?>
      </td>
      <td class="actions">
        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
          <li>
            <a title="Vezi fisa" href="view_record.php?mid=<?php echo $mid; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Editeaza" href="edit_record.php?mid=<?php echo $mid; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a title="Sterge" class="delete-icn" href="#" data-mid="<?php echo $mid; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } mysqli_free_result($result); } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`" . $row['uid'] . ";`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo $row['first_name'] . $row['last_name'];
}
```

instead of

```
echo $sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`" . $row['uid'] . ";`";
 echo $row['first_name'] . $row['last_name'];
```

The best way is to join user and medical_records table as below in the first sql.

```
$sql = "SELECT m.mid, m.uid, m.nume_complet, m.judet, m.data_internarii_mamei, m.ora_internarii_mamei, m.data_operatiei, m.ora_operatiei, u.first_name, u.last_name FROM medical_records m join users u on m.uid = u.id";
```

and below is not needed

```
echo $sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name` FROM users WHERE id =`" . $row['uid'] . ";`";
```